# Is ssl termination at AWS load balancer ELB secure?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, amazon-elb

We have a web application running on ec2 instance.
We have added AWS ELB to route all request to application to load balancer.
SSL certificate has been applied to ELB.

I am worried about whether HTTP communication between ELB and ec2 instance is secure?
or 
should I use HTTPS communication between ELB and ec2 instance?

Does AWS guarantees security of HTTP communication between ELB and ec2 instance?

Answer (score 4):

I answered a [similar question once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13658525/security-implications-of-mysql-aws-security-group-set-up/13667076#13667076) but would like to highlight some points:

1. Use VPC with proper Security Groups setup (must) and network ACL (optional).
2. Notice your private keys distribution. AWS made it easy with storing it safely in their system and never using it again on your servers. It is probably better to use self-signed certificates on your servers (reducing the chance to leak your real private keys)
3. SSL is cheap these days (compute wise)
4. It all depends on your security requirements, regulations and how much complexity overhead are you willing to take.
5. AWS do provide [some guaranties (see network section)](http://d36cz9buwru1tt.cloudfront.net/pdf/AWS_Security_Whitepaper.pdf) against spoofing / retrieval of information by other tenants, but the safe assumption is that multi-tenant public cloud environment is not 100% hygienic and you should encrypt.
6. Single tenant instance (as suggested by @andreimarinescu) will not help as the attack vector discussed here is the network between the ELB (shared env) and your instance. (however, it might help against XEN zero days)
7. Long answer with short summary - encrypt.

Answer (score 1):

Absolute control over security and cloud deployments are in my opinion two things that don't mix very well.

Regarding the security of traffic between the ELB and the EC2 instances, you should probably deploy your resources in a VPC in order to add a new layer of isolation. AWS doesn't offer any security guarantees.

If the data transferred is too sensitive, you might also want to look at deploying in a dedicated data-center where you can have greater control over the networking aspects. Also, you might want to look at single-tenant instances on EC2, since you're probably sharing your physical resources with other EC2 customers.

That being said, there's one aspect that you also should take into account: SSL termination is quite an expensive job, so terminating SSL at the ELB level will allow your backend instances to focus resources on actually fulfilling the requests, but this will also impact the ELB (it will automatically scale, but it will have to do it faster, and you might see increased latency as it does so during spikes of traffic).

Comment: You should be deploying in a VPC, and any recent accounts will do so automatically.